# Getting error when installing tts-watson in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to install tts-watson in my machine. I did it using "pip install tts-watson" in the command prompt and it worked. But when I try to install it in Pycharm it doesn't work. This is the error I am getting:

"AssertionError: anyconfig .dist-info directory not found"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what's `tts-watson` why don't you install the python-sdk using `pip install watson-developer-cloud`

Comment: this is the module in python for Watson - Text-To-Speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tts-watson is a , https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson , pip module that hasn't been updated for over 2 years, and has been broken for almost a year - https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson/issues/3 .

You should try `watson-developer-cloud` instead.